# a C++ program that loads over 1 billion records into memory?

Tags: c++, database, boost, stl, shared-memory

I have a whole years worth of option prices in a database (along with other bits of information such as strike price, volatility etc) and would like to load it into memory for my program to process (hash maps, program was written in C++). The trouble is it takes over 10 hours to load into memory at startup (from a local database).

Can someone please suggest how i can overcome this issue ? I have workarounds where i only load the portions that i need but it would be great if people can share ideas to the problem. Would loading the data from shared memory after each startup help?

Here is the code so far, in short it queries the database and loads the data into containers

```
    const std::string m_url = "mysql://localhost/test2?user=root&password=";
    URL_T optionURL = URL_new(m_url.c_str());
    ConnectionPool_T optionPool = ConnectionPool_new(optionURL);
    ConnectionPool_setInitialConnections(optionPool,1);
    ConnectionPool_setMaxConnections(optionPool,1);
    ConnectionPool_start(optionPool);
    Connection_T con = ConnectionPool_getConnection(optionPool);
    ResultSet_T result = Connection_executeQuery(con,
                                                 "SELECT DISTINCT(underlying) FROM  Options");
    PreparedStatement_T prepareStatement = Connection_prepareStatement(con,"SELECT  underlying,underlyingPrice,expiry,strike,issueDate,type,delta,volatility FROM Options  o,RiskFreeRate r WHERE underlying = ? AND o.issueDate = r.date");

    while(ResultSet_next(result))
    {
        const std::string symbol = ResultSet_getString(result,1);
        PreparedStatement_setString(prepareStatement,1,symbol.c_str());
        ResultSet_T resultDetail  = PreparedStatement_executeQuery(prepareStatement);
        while(ResultSet_next(resultDetail))
        {
            float strike = ResultSet_getDouble(resultDetail,4);
            date expiry = from_string(ResultSet_getString(resultDetail,3));
            std::string issueDate = ResultSet_getString(resultDetail,5);
            float underlyingPrice = ResultSet_getDouble(resultDetail,2);
            float riskFreeRate = 4; //tmp hack
            float volatility = ResultSet_getDouble(resultDetail,8);
            OptionDateMap optionMap = m_optionMap[symbol];
            OptionVec optionVec = optionMap[issueDate];
            optionVec.push_back(boost::shared_ptr<WallStreet::FixedIncome::Option::Option> (new WallStreet::FixedIncome::Option::Option(strike,expiry,underlyingPrice, riskFreeRate,volatility)));
            optionMap[issueDate] = optionVec;
            m_optionMap[symbol] = optionMap;

    }
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is your hardware setup?

Comment: it is a mac, i am running this on a local box nothing fancy with 4gb of memory

Comment: i am not sure why this question has been put on hold, it is a perfectly valid question, i am sure people have run into limitations like this and it would be great if they can share ideas

Comment: spontaneously it sounds more suited for a database.

Comment: @claptrap according to OP stuff is in a database already.

Comment: Can you aggregate/summarize portions of the dataset?

Comment: well not in this case no, i was more curious to know whether loading it into boost shared memory and then reading from that after each startup would help?

Comment: Please post a section of the code on how you are obtaining the data.

Comment: ok i have posted the code,

Comment: Is it a problem reading from the database, or allocating the memory (you application starts paging, etc.).  1bn records is a lot, especially with only 4G memory.  `map` is going to use a lot of memory over a flat data structure (like 'vector` which can be sorted and subsequently searched using a binary search).  However, with no details it's not clear exactly what your bottleneck is.

Comment: @godzilla: First, stop copying `optionMap` and `optionVec`. And, preferably, allocating memory with `new` for `Option` on every iteration...

Comment: Have you run it through a profiler?  It is entierly possible that your code is waiting on SQL the entire time.

Comment: @vlad I have changed the lines from OptionDateMap optionMap = m_optionMap[symbol]; to OptionDateMap &optionMap = m_optionMap[symbol]; and it speeded things up considerably, i will test  it again but can you spot anything else?

Comment: If i used memory mapped filesystem and read from that upon start up would that help?

Comment: @godzilla: I can, of course. But instead of having me spotting, just use a profiler!

Comment: can you recommend a profiler?

Comment: 10^9 records with 4*10^9 (approx) memory... unless your records (and data structures) are really tiny, that won't fit. You are going to end up swapping to disk continuously and that is going to kill the performance. If you want to manage that amount of data as a block in memory you should get better hardware. Once you have better hardware you might want to consider better software approaches, but with your current setup it is impossible.

Comment: @vlad if i got rid of  optionMap[issueDate] = optionVec; and  m_optionMap[symbol] = optionMap; would it help?